# EntityFrameworkCore FindAsync does not get inserted record without SaveChanges

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, abp

I have a list of products and getting their stock from database with `FindAsync()`. If `FindAsync` does not get record I insert product to stock with `InsertAsync()`. And then if i call `FindAsync()` second time for same Product Id, i still do not get Stock record and my code tries to insert record to Stock second time. I need to Find stock of product and if stock exists, update stock quantity. How can i find also newly inserted records without calling `SaveChangesAsync()` in foreach loop.

```
foreach (var product in products)
{
    var stock = await stockRepository.FindAsync(product.Id);
    if (stock == null)
    {
        stock = new Stock(SequenceGenerator.Create(SequenceType.Default), product.Id, quantity);
        stock = await stockRepository.InsertAsync(stock);
    }
    else
    {
        stock.Quantity += quantity;
        stock = await stockRepository.UpdateAsync(stock);
    }                
    await uow.SaveChangesAsync();              
}
```

Comment: Try with stock.Result==null (Synchronous)

Comment: There's no `InsertAsync` or `UpdateAsync` in EF Core. Nor any `uow` or `Repository`. We can't guess what your own classes do unless you post your code. EF Core has no problems though, nor does it need any "repository" or "unit of work" wrappers. A DbContext is already a Unit-of-Work, a DbSet is already a repository. Changes are already tracked cached by DbContext until `SaveChanges` is called. At this point all changes are persisted using a single internal transaction. **That's** how a UoW is supposed to work.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I thought that nothing would be saved to the database (and therefore findable) until SaveChangeAsync has finished.   EF is a unit of work, and the UoW is not completed until SaveChanges has completed.  You could either keep track of the records that have yet to be committed and not bother looking them up, or even have a child transaction.

Comment: "a DbSet is already a repository" - This bears repeating for those who insist on layering another repository on top of it because they just learned about design patterns.

Comment: It looks like you used the "generic repository" **anti**pattern, breaking EF Core's Repository and UoW functionality. DbContext already tracks entities (unless you disable change tracking). `DbSet.Find` will first look for any cached entities before hitting the database.

Comment: You *don't* need a low-lever Repository when you use an ORM - EF Core is a *higher* level abstraction. ORMs like EF Core already offer far better generic interfaces than the CRUD interface typical "generic repos" offer (which is actually a Data Access Object, not a repository). You *may* need a *specialized* service/repository that would abstract differences between using eg an ORM, GraphQL or a document/graph database. At this point the data access and morre importantly, transactional differences are *huge* and no CRUD/"generic repo" can handle them.

Comment: BTW in real code you'd *never* load items one by one, resulting in N queries for N objects. You'd load them all in a single query, modify them and then persist all of them. That's just 2 queries instead of the 2*N queries individual loading would cost. No explicit transaction would be needed either. Instead of `Find`, extract the IDs of the new products in a list with eg `products.Select(p=>p.Id).ToList()`, and use `var storedProducts=_dbContext.Products.Where(p=>ids.Contains(p.Id)).ToList()` to load all matching products.

Comment: *"You don't need a low-lever Repository when you use an ORM"* - You do, because the repositories isolate the BI layer from the persistance layer. You use entities in your datalayer, and dtos in your web app. You **must never** use your entities in your web app. Never. A specific ex: a user wants to turn on 2FA from the profile page. This is done through one api endpoint. Or the user wants to simply update his username/password. This is done through a second endpoint. There you pull the entity from the database (single source of truth), update only the columns that matter, and save the changes.

Comment: @Pieterjan No, you don't, because ORM provides the repository for you. This doesn't force you to use your entities (which entities btw - from data model (ORM), or domain model etc. - these are generally different) as dtos directly. End points, controllers, services - all these can do what you are saying using the ORM provided repository/uow

Comment: Start by not using abp :)

Comment: @Pieterjan who said about using data entities in the app? That's why we use *any* data access pattern, so we don't have to do that. As for those nevers, they apply to the code we wrote before 2000 and *maybe* VB6. After that we always had better abstractions, definitely better than the data-access object you have in mind when you say "repository". A class that abstracts CRUD operations is a data access object, not a repository. We used to write those by hand until we got NHibernate and Entity Framework. ORMs in .NET were huge up to 2010. ORMs do far more than CRUD

Comment: @Pieterjan besides, even when you use a well designed repository to manage *business* entities, you *still* don't treat them as DTOs, except in rare cases. Never mind that there's not a single DTO. A [famous tweet](https://twitter.com/mamund/status/767212233759657984?lang=en) says `your data model is not your object model is not your resource model is not your message model`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what InsertAsync() or UpdateAsync are doing but you'll have to attach the object then either set the entity state to added or modified:

```
var attached = dbContext.Attach(stock);
attached.State = EntityState.Added;
```

Or

```
var attached =dbContext.Attach(stock);
attached.State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: Not even that most likely. If new objects have a default ID value, `dbContext.Update` will attach the object as Added.

Answer (score 0):

You should always add the boolean, when inserting new objects to the database in Abp framework
`stockRepository.InsertAsync(stock, true);`